# C# guessing game with customised buttons

Tags: c#

i have a button that determines whether the guess of the number was too high now i know what needs to be done but doing it is another thing entirely, when i press the button reset it starts with a new random number now if it is too high ill press the too high button and now that guessed number lets say its 32, that 32 becomes the maxValue now how do i write a statement in my button method to do that i have so far.

```
int input = random.Next(minValue, maxValue).ToString();
```

witch gives me the random number to begin with so how do i get the make the guessed number the initial maxValue if its too high or the minValue if its too low.

please help thanks.

Comment: Wait a second! You using `.ToString()` and store it in `int`? Why? I think you should read a book.

Comment: There's noway nobody can help you if you don't ask your question better than that and post relevant code...

Comment: Please post your problem. By a brief look I can say that you have posted the project requirement.

Answer (score 0):

First off, welcome to Stack Overflow, and please check the faq.

As much as I'd like you to write a little more concisely and do some reading, I'll try and give you some tips.

I'm writing this based on what I think I understood reading your question.

Assuming the question is this: `how do i get the make the guessed number the initial maxValue if its too high or the minValue if its too low.`

Or, as I interpreted, **How do I make maxValue become the guessed number if it is too high, or do the same thing to minValue if its too low?**

First off:

```
int input = random.Next(minValue, maxValue).ToString();
```

As Soner commented, why are you converting the result to string? And more importantly, why is this variable called `input` if it's random? Not that it's wrong, but it's a bit misleading.

Well, let's make the initial min/max as 0/100

```
int minValue = 0;
int maxValue = 100;
int secretNumber = random.Next(minValue, maxValue);
```

The secret number will be between 0 and 100. Then you guess a number. I'm assuming this guess number is random as well, because you wrote it that way.

```
int guess = random.Next(minValue, maxValue);
```

Then you said, "make the guessed number the initial maxValue if its too high"

```
if (tooHigh && guess<maxValue){ //you pressed "Too High"
    maxValue = guess;
}
```

I think you can go on from here.